# How to create File div effect in CSS

Tags: css

How to create this effect in div with CSS?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTTyi.png)

I've done this with before and after, but I'm not that good with these tags:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4TwL.png)

I'm sorry if I'm asking the question wrong, but could you help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working version of a file in CSS. Note—I made the element a `button`—not a `div`, because usually these types of things are clicked by users. Maintaining accessibility standards is key and should drive the type of markup (HTML) you choose.

The `aria-label` is used by screen readers to share a better description of the element with which the user is interacting. Without it, a blind user, for example, would only know that this was a button with "PDF" as the text.

The CSS is pretty straightforward, but please let me know if anything needs to be explained further.

```css
.file {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 4rem;
  min-height: 5rem;
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
  margin: 2em auto;
  color: #fff;
  background: #97C02F;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff #fff #658E15 #658E15;
  background: #658E15;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-width: 16px;
  border-color: #fff #fff transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.file span {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.55rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="file" aria-label="click to view PDF file">
  <span>PDF</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Andy.

I'm studying CSS, hence my difficulty.

Your explanation was of great help.
Thank you one more time.

God bless you.